# Excel get first instance of value below the row based from a text string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following in Excel:

[image: Excel problem]

In Column D, if Row B (e.g. B2) has CHECKIN on it, through C2 where the Barcode value is recorded (e.g. 0007890), I want to iterate to the next rows such that I get to the next instance of 0007890 and get the corresponding Idnumber (which is MD0002). So in D2, I should get the value of MD0002. I'm trying out MATCH and INDEX but can't seem to make it work. I hope you can help me what I wanted to get.

The sample output should be like below:
[image: Excel result]

Thanks and cheers!

Comment: Is the `0007890` chosen by the user, or is it chosen because it was the first with `Checkin`

Comment: Chosen because it has CHECKIN on it. Everything that has CHECKINs are to be captured.

Comment: How should the output look like for the two checkins in your example. Please provide a picture of your desired output

Comment: @schnydszch Please edit your original post to clarify.  As you can see, it is difficult to tell what you want from the formatting in your comment

Comment: Ooppss sorry, edited the original post. Thanks!

Comment: Will the `CHECKIN` barcode always appear after that row, or could it appear before, like you have `0004269` for both `MD0003` and `MD0001`, you want the NEXT match correct?

Comment: The CHECKIN barcode can appear either before and after Tim. I just want the next match, there could actually be more, but I just sent a small sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula in D2 and copy down.

```
=IF(B2="CHECKIN",IFERROR(INDEX(B3:$B$1040000,MATCH(C2,C3:$C$1040000,0)),"#"),"#")
```

[image]